# How to free allocated memory in a recursive function in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, recursion

I have a recursive method in a class that computes some stages (doesn't matter what this is). If it notice that the probability of success for a stage is to low, the stage will be delayed by storing it in a queue and the program will look for delayed stage later. It grabs a stage, copies the data for working and deletes the stage.

The program runs fine, but I got a memory problem. Since this program is randomized it could happen that it delays up to 10 million stages which results in something like 8 to 12 GB memory usage (or more but it crashes before that happens). It seems the program never frees the memory for a deleted stage before reaching the end of the call stack of the recursive function.

```
class StageWorker
{
private:
    queue<Stage*> delayedStages;

    void perform(Stage** start)
    {
       // [long value_from_stage = (**start).value; ]

       delete *start;

       // Do something here

       // Delay a stage if necessary like this
       this->delayedStages.push(new Stage(value));

       // Do something more here

       // Look for delayed stages like this
       Stage* front = this->delayedStages.front();
       this->delayedStages.pop();
       this->perform(&front);
    }
}
```

I use pointer to pointer as I thought the memory is not freed, because there is a pointer (front*) that points to the stage. So I used a pointer that point to the pointer, and so I can delete it. But it seems not to work. If I watch the memory usage on Performance monitor (on Windows) it like like this:
[image: Memory usage with marked end of recursive calls]
I marked the end of the recursive calls. This is also just a example plot. real data, but in a very small scenario.

Any ideas how to free the memory of not longer used sages before reaching the end of the call stack?

**Edit**
I followed some advice and removed the pointers. So now it looks like this:

```
class StageWorker
{
private:
    queue<Stage> delayedStages;

    void perform(Stage& start)
    {
       // [long value_from_stage = start.value; ]

       // Do something here

       // Delay a stage if necessary like this
       this->delayedStages.push(Stage(value));

       // Do something more here

       // Look for delayed stages like this          
       this->perform(this->delayedStages.front());
       this->delayedStages.pop();
    }
}
```

But this changed nothing, memory usage is the same as before.

As mentioned it maybe is a problem of monitoring. Is there a better way to check the exact memory usage?

Comment: Just a question: why `std::queue<Stage*>` and not `std::queue<Stage>`? Ie, why don't you want to let the standard library take care of memory management for you? If c++11 is not an issue, you can even use `emplace` if you are concerned about copying Stages.

Comment: Also `So I used a pointer that point to the pointer, and so I can delete it.`: a reference to the pointer would be so much clearer.

Comment: A good first start would be to remove all pointer stuff, including in particular `new` and `delete`. Just *move* your `Stage` objects.

Comment: I tried this first but this also seems not to work... maybe I have done anything wrong. I can not tell... As I understand it, the garbage collection will handle it also after the first called recursive call has finished, but this is to late. With a reference to the pointer it seems that I can not delete the pointer.

Comment: You are aware that the memory usage in Windows is probably not immediately showing every free that you make, but will only free a block of memory when a larger block is free - in particular, if you delete the "middle" of a large chunk of memory, it may not be freed until the "end" has been freed too. It would be worth writing a simple program that just does memory allocation in recursive way, and some sleep, then free again, to see that your assumptions on "how memory is reflected" matches reality (or shows up the way you expect).

Comment: @MatsPetersson oh.. ok this could be the problem... but how should i solve this?

Comment: @MatsPetersson You might be right, but wouldn't it be surprising if that was the problem, considering that `queue`s are specifically designed to handle FIFO queuing? I'd say the problem here is using 10M times `new` and `delete` for (supposedly) small objects.

Comment: What exactly do you want to solve? That your application appears to have more memory allocated than it really has? Why is that a problem? As long as your application doesn't leak, and your application doesn't run out of memory [or some other application runs out of memory], where is the problem? It's an optimisation in the heap management to not free small portions of memory and/or free memory that are "holes" in the middle of a large chunk - the OS does that because it expects the memory to be used again. Instead, it frees the memory when a "large enough, contiguous chunk" is available.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: Not sure we're talking about the same thing. I'm talking about the fact that if you allocate a bunch of things, and then free them in a different order, the OS doesn't necessarily record that you have released a bunch of small objects until the whole lot is freed again. Internally, within the heap management, the blocks are "available" to be used, but the the memory is not freed back to the OS to help speed up re-allocation and avoid having to "compact" the heap.

Comment: The problem is that the application runs out of memory (some times). There are runs where in total 7 million stages were stored and after deleting 6 million the programm still uses memory for 7 million.

Comment: If storing so many items is a problem then you might consider a different algorithm where you don't need to defer as many, or you process some or all of the deferred items once you hit a particular limit.

Comment: Yes, I'm also doing this. The algorithm I'm using is a research project, so I first try to reduce the memory usage of my implementation.

Comment: Right, so the apparent memory usage and actual memory usage aren't matching - in other words, your monitoring of the memory usage is not telling the whole truth - it tells you the apparent memory usage. Which is fine for determining what application is using a lot of memory, etc, but not for determining how much memory is actually in active use by your application is using at a precise moment in time. You would need to know how much memory is actually freed out of that memory. Like I said, write a very simple program that follows your pattern.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are not running out of memory because you simply need more than there is, rather than because you are not freeing it? Alternatively, are you perhaps allocating large hunks that cause memory fragmentation?

Comment: Yes it needs a lot of memory. The image looked like memory is not freed, so i thought i can reduce the memory usage by 50% or more by deleting stages right. If you say the memory is freed but the os dont get it, it changes some things. Do you know if freed memory that is not handed back to the operating system can be used by the application again? if this is the case, everything is fine and i just have to look for other ways to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: I now looked closer to the number of delaed stages and how it changes and what effect this has to the memory usage i see in the monitor. I saw that 10,000 stages were delayed, then about 2000 were freed (memory usage did not go down) but then 1700 were stored and the memory usage does not go up. So it looks like the freed memory was reused. seems like i have to look for other ways to reduce the memory usage. thanks a lot for showing me where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question as answered:

Mats Petersson (thanks a lot) mentiond in the comments that it could be a problem of monitoring the memory usage.

In fact this exactly was the problem. The code I provided in the edit (after replacing the pointers by references) frees the space correctly, but it is not given back to the OS (in this case Windows). So from the monitor it looks like the space is not freed.

But then I made some experiments and saw that freed memory is reused by the application, so it does not have to ask the OS for more memory.

So what the monitor shows is the maximum memory used bevore getting back the whole memory the recursive function required, after the first call of this function ends.

Comment: So what you see is the maximum amount of memory that your program uses at some point during its life time, and it's too large for big numbers of stages. Which means that the millions of objects which are in the queue at some (maximum) point occupy too much memory. Not much you can do about it imho if confronted with so many stages and that algorithm. But perhaps you can save not complete stage objects in the queue but instead only some small information sufficient to re-create them?

Comment: yes, I have to limit the maximum of stages in some way. I already reduced a stage to the minimum information i need to restore the full information of a stage. Now i will think about a way to limit the number of stored stages without breaking the algorithm. But the question was only, if I can improve the memory usage by freeing the memory. Now I know, this already works.